# rails check box hidden field class

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, view, checkbox, hidden-field

I have been wondering how to add a class to the hidden field that is generated with the view helper f.check_box ? The purpose is to manage those fields with javascript at later time. I did not find any documentation that talks about it anywhere.

Update:

The only solution seems to be DIY with a check_box_tag, eg:

`<input name="customs_info[0][hs_code_save]" class="hs_code_save_hidden" type="hidden" value="0">

<%= check_box_tag "customs_info[0][hs_code_save]", "", false, class:"hs_code_save", style:"width:60px" %>`

Answer (score 2):

Right now you can't do it with rails' `check_box` helper but you definitely can grab this hidden fields by querying it with `input[name=your-input-name][type=hidden]` or something